# ionic2:how can I use transfer to upload multiple files at the same time?

Tags: upload, ionic2

I want to upload several pictures to server at the same time,the native plugin provide `transfer`,but this plugin can only upload a file at the same time.I don't want to call `transfer.upload` in `while` or `for`.
What method can upload multiple files at the same time? Thank you very much for your reply!!!  http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/transfer/

Comment: look this blog,i solved it: http://www.longdw.com/ionic2-imagepicker-multiple-file-upload/

Answer (score 0):

Even though the example is for angularjs/ionic..,give it a try

Go through this tutorial.,you will get a some idea to proceed further.
https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/01/upload-files-remote-server-using-ionic-framework/

Comment: thank you.after a few days of trying,eventually failed to solve this problem.

Comment: this can only upload a file to serve.i upload a file to server with transfer successfully.but i don't know how to upload multiple files.